# How can I make a filter for checking if a discord user is in a server?

Tags: javascript, filter, discord.js

How can I make a filter that filters out non-server members from an array of users in discord.js?

I've tried

```
let serverMemberFilter = async obj => {
    if (await message.guild.members.fetch(obj.id)) return true;
    // obj.id is the user id
    else return false;
}
```

however that just crashes my bot with the "Unknown Member" error, which I assume is because it is going over a user that isn't a member.

I've also tried

```
let serverMemberFilter = async obj => {
    let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
    return members.has(obj.id);
}
```

but it gets stuck "awaiting".

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.resolve()`, instead of fetch. It's synchronous.

```
let serverMemberFilter = async obj => {
    return message.guild.members.resolve(obj.id) !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `.resolve()`? It uses the cache which does not always contain all of the server members.